# Using tensorflow-slim weights for transfer learning using tflearn?

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn, tf-slim

The weights obtained from the tfslim library are in the form of ckpt. Would it be possible to reinstate the weights to a graph created manually using either pure tensorflow or tflearn (ideally)? My only worry is if the architecture is slightly different, then the weights in the ckpt could not be used at all.

Has transfer learning been done through using tfslim weights but without using tfslim (I currently find tflearn easier to learn compared to tfslim, and so would like to focus on tflearn instead)?